# Spinner DropDown List

Tags: android

I have four Spinner, Which has a custom background with drop down list. When click on third and fourth spinner then its list showing above the spinner not to down the spinner. Also My screen has lot's of space, but I don't know how to solve this problem.
I am using below layout to show spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_screen"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/solarparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="Full Name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameTxtView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="16"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="System Size (kW)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ppaSystemSizeEditView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="kW"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Annual Production"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/annualLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/annualTxyView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:hint="Select"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textColorHint="#000000"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="kWh/kW/yr"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="PPA Term (Years)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/ppaSpiner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                    android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="Years"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="PPA Escalation Rate (%)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/escalationSpiner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                    android:prompt="@string/spinner_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="%"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="PPA Cap (\u20B9/kWH)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/ppaCapSpiner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="/kWH"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Customer Deposit Tenure (Months)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/ppaDepositSpiner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                    android:prompt="@string/spinner_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="Months"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Special Requirements"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/requelayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/spclDialogTxtView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                            android:text="Select"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="16"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_calculate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_btn_selector"
                android:text="Calculate"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="PPA Year 1 Rate (\u20B9/kWH)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ppayearrate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:text="16"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but_cal_saving"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_btn_selector"
                    android:text="Calculate Savings"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but_Home"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_btn_selector"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cippa_font" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>


and below is my spinner.bg for Spinner background :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><layer-list>
            <item><shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#504a4b" />

                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape></item>
            <item><bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/dropdown_spinner" />
            </item>
        </layer-list></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Try adding this line to the `spinner` : `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`

Comment: I have tried, but not working.If I remove background, then it work perfect.

Comment: set your background this way android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"

Comment: If you set the weight of spinner you should set the width or height to 0 try changing this may be this causes the problem

Comment: 0 width or height not showing spinner and popup background is use for list not for spinner so both are not working for me.

Comment: It actually creates problem for last two spinners also I have changed the position of Spinner then it create a problem for another spinner not for before one, In case of Spinner background.